# MLP classifier_for multi class

Tags: keras, confusion-matrix, multiclass-classification

I am newbie on keras,

I try to follow the Keras tutorial for Multilayer Perceptron (MLP) for multi-class softmax classification, using my data set.
My data has 3 classes and only one feature, but I don't understand why the result always show just 0,3 of accuracy and the model predicted all training data as first class. then the confusion matrix is like this.

[Confusion matrix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2lo9e.jpg)

Here the coding:

```python
import keras
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Activation
from keras.optimizers import SGD
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np



# Importing the dataset
dataset = pd.read_csv('StatusAll.csv')
X = dataset.iloc[:, 1:].values
y = dataset.iloc[:, 0:1].values


# Splitting the dataset into the Training set and Test set
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 0.2, random_state = 0)

from keras.utils import to_categorical
y_train = to_categorical(y_train)
y_test = to_categorical(y_test)

model = Sequential()

# Dense(64) is a fully-connected layer with 64 hidden units.
# in the first layer, you must specify the expected input data shape:
# here, 20-dimensional vectors.
model.add(Dense(64, activation='tanh', input_dim=1))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(64, activation='tanh'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(4, activation='softmax'))

sgd = SGD(lr=0.01, decay=1e-6, momentum=0.9, nesterov=True)

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              optimizer=sgd,
              metrics=['accuracy'])

history = model.fit(x_train, y_train,
          epochs=100,
          batch_size=128)
score = model.evaluate(x_test, y_test, batch_size=128)
print('Test score:', score[0])
print('Test accuracy:', score[1])


from sklearn import metrics

prediction = model.predict(x_test)
prediction = np.around(prediction)

y_test_non_category = [ np.argmax(t) for t in y_test ]
y_predict_non_category = [ np.argmax(t) for t in prediction ]

from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
conf_mat = confusion_matrix(y_test_non_category, y_predict_non_category)

print (conf_mat)
```

I hope I can get some advice, thanksss.

The x_train example
[x_train](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ErV4.jpg)

[y_train before converted to categorical](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZMpqL.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eqMM3.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

Your final Dense layer has 4 outputs, it seems like you are classifying 4 instead of 3.

```
model.add(Dense(3, activation='softmax')) # Number of classes 3
```

It would be helpful to see sample data from x_train and y_train to make sure the pre-processing is correct. Because you have only 1 feature, a MLP might be overkill. A [decision tree](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/tree.html) would be simpler unless you want to experiment with MLPs.

Comment: Thanks for make me aware that I made a mistake to that part, by the way after I changed it into 3 classes, then I still face the same problem, the confusion matrix still like that. however, I provide the the example of the sample of x_train and y_train. Thankss @nuric